# calculating the variance of an orthogonal line

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I have three points $A(x,y) , B(x,y)$ and $C(x,y)$ the $x$ and $y$ coordinates follow a normal distribution with a known mean and variance. I don,t know if $A$ and $B$ are correlated with each other. I know $C$ dont have an correlation with $A$ and $B$.

There is a line made bij $AB$ and the point $C$. i want to calculate the distance from $C$ to the line $AB$. that means there is an orthogonal line from $C$ on $AB$. the length of that line is calculed with the next formule : $det(A)/|a-b|$ $A$ is an matrix made bij $(a-c,a-b)$

Atm i am using a *monte carlo* simulation to find the variance and mean. with the simulation, i found that the distance follow a normal distribution.
Anyone can help me out?
Is it possible to calculate the variance of the length of the orthogonal line without the use of a simulation?

[image: the plot of the lines (road map)]
I am not allowed to upload the plot of the points. the dataframe of the points excist of 4096 points located on the map. i have to find for each point a line with the smallest distence. the points are from an other map. the company want to combine those maps to create an better map

Comment: Do the $x$ and $y$ follow different distributions for different points A,B and C?

Comment: yes. they follow different distributions.(still normal distributed but different variance)

Comment: This looks like a street map. If you can not share the data, could you maybe explain the *nature* of the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributions can be wildly varying depending on the distributions of A, B and C.

So I think that it will be difficult to give a simple solution if there is not a clear specification of the distribution, based on which simplifications can be made.

#### Example for a funny distribution

Let A and B be two distributions centered around $(0,0)$ with A very small variance and B a very large variance.

This makes that the line between A and B is more or less the line through $(0,0)$ and B, or a line through $(0,0)$ with an angle that is homogeneously distributed.

Let C be a distribution far away from $(0,0)$ with small variance. In the computed example below, we used C centered around $(10,0)$

[image: example]

Then the distance of C from the line is more or less equal to

$$d \approx 10 \sin(\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between the line through point B and the x-axis.

If we consider the angle is homogenously distributed from $0$ to $\pi$ then you can compute the distribution of $d$ [by transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables):

$$\theta = \sin^{-1}(d/10)$$

and the derivative can be used to compute the distribution of the transformed variable

$$f(d) = \frac{2}{\pi \sqrt{100-d^2}}$$

**Computation example:**

[image: example]

```r
set.seed(1)

### https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points
distance <- function(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2) {
  abs((y2-y1)*x0-(x2-x1)*y0+x2*y1-y2*x1)/sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
}

n <- 10^4
x0 <- rnorm(n,mean = 10,sd = 0.1)
y0 <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 0.1)
x1 <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 2)
y1 <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 2)
x2 <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 0.1)
y2 <- rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 0.1)

d <- distance(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2)

hist(d, breaks = seq(0,11,0.2), freq = 0, main = "histogram of d \n with theoretic density curve")
ds <- seq(0,10,0.1)
lines(ds , (2/pi)/sqrt(100-ds^2))
```

Comment: the only thing i know is that c has a small distribution. A and B can be different. is there an easy solution of A en B use an equal variance?

Comment: Also there is one thing i forgot. the *x* and *y* coordinates of A and B are not equal. it is possible that a C=A or C=B

Comment: @J.Kuiper I am afraid that these pieces of information are not enough to make the problem simpler.

Comment: @J.Kuiper aren't you accepting this answer prematurely? The answer explains why the type of distributions of the distance can vary a lot for the given problem setup, but I can imagine that it is possible to describe it more precisely and some approximations might be possible if you would have better descriptions of the distributions of the points a, b and c.

Comment: the problem is, i don.t have an better discription of a,b,c.
I have an list of points C with given variance,
I have an list of lines with starting point A and End point B. those points are points on a (inaccurate) map. 
i don,t have any more information about those points

Comment: @J.Kuiper could you provide a plot and explain what these points/lines mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116168/discussion-between-j-kuiper-and-sextus-empiricus).